# How to have jQuery display the next nearest <tr> in a table and attach a jquery function to a class for multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Firstly, an Apology**

Help... I've got brain-freeze. I'm a reasonably accomplished jQuery fiddler and usually I can piece together what I need from the API docs/examples/existing SO questions, but I can't seem to manage it this time round.

Hopefully I don't get down-voted too much for this embarrassing question.

**Setting the scene**

I have a table currently with as few as 1 and up to - essentially - limitless possible rows within it. What I need to do is for each `<tr>` row, is have another `<tr>` below it that defaults to `display: none;`. So far, so good.

[image: Current table example - before any of what I describe below!]

At the end of each row is a dropdown select box with several options, as per the above.

**What I need help with...**

What I want to achieve is attaching a jQuery handler to these dropdowns and, if the value 'Partial Accept' is selected, I want to unhide (`.show()`) the hidden `<tr>` as it will contain a few additional input fields to identify how many are being accepted, and why the remainder have been rejected (e.g. 'to follow', or 'damaged', and so on).

**My question is** what's the best way to achieve this dynamically? I've got as far as it involving `.next()` somewhere along the line, if I attach the jQuery handler to a class and the dropdowns all being of that class? But I can't work out how to fit it all together.

**I appreciate this question has no code** - I was wondering if some kind soul would take pity on this worn-out programmer and give an example of how you'd achieve it, given the above description and screenshot?

Thank you all in advance for your insights. ~~Lee

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").next().show()` is not that exotic.

Comment: @Jon Indeed it isn't. I did say it was embarrassing... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From whatever I understood of the question - You want to toggle the `next row` of `parent tr`, if the dropdown value is `Something`.

Try this -

```
$(".dropdownClass").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Something") {
        $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").show();
    } else {
        $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").hide();
    }
});
```

Untested, but you get the sense...

Edit:
Changed `parent("tr")` to `closest("tr")`

Comment: I can make something with this and Jon's comment. Thank you for taking the time to answer a silly question... I really appreciate it.

Comment: missing a close quote on the first line

Comment: plus, should be `closest` instead of `parent`. Fiddle I was working on when you answered: http://jsfiddle.net/49HEb/

Comment: Thanks @CupawnTae. Yes it should be `closest`, `parent` only checks one level up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're talking about, but just whipped this up quick and found a solution with `.change()`:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;" id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Hi!</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Hello!</td>
    </tr>
   <tr style="border: 1px solid black; display: table-row;">
     <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Missed</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<select id="hello">
  <option>Hi!</option>
  <option>Hello!</option>
</select>
<script>
var hider = $("#table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3)");
$("#hello").change(function() {
    if (this.value === "Hello!") hider.show();
    else hider.hide();
});
</script>
```